# Pegar o valor da tabela javaScript e colocar em um array

Tags: javascript, json

Estou com um problema, fiz uma tabela dinâmica em JavaScript e quero jogar seus dados em um array, tentei usar JSON mas quando clico no botão para executar o evento não faz nada. Não sei se está faltando algum plugin, pois nunca havia trabalhado com JSON, segue o código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <!-- Aqui esta o meu script para criar a tabela  -->
    <title> Controle de Material </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      totals = 0;
      function adiciona() {
        totals++

        var tbl = document.getElementById("tabelaPedido");
        var novaLinha = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        var novaCelula;

        if(totals%2==0)
          cl = "#FFFFFF";
        else
          cl = "##FFFFFF";

        novaCelula = novaLinha.insertCell(0);
        novaCelula.align = "left";
        novaCelula.style.backgroundColor = cl;
        novaCelula.innerHTML = document.getElementById('cprod').value;

        totals;

        novaCelula = novaLinha.insertCell(1);
        novaCelula.align = "left";
        novaCelula.style.backgroundColor = cl;
        novaCelula.innerHTML =  document.getElementById('cquant').value;
        novaCelula2 = novaLinha.insertCell(2);
        novaCelula.align = "left";
        novaCelula.style.backgroundColor = cl;

        var btnEl = document.createElement('input');

        btnEl.setAttribute('type', 'button');
        btnEl.setAttribute('class', 'btn');

        btnEl.onclick = function () {
          deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)
        };

        btnEl.setAttribute('value', 'Delete');
        novaCelula2.appendChild(btnEl);
      }

      //Função para excluir a linha
      function deleteRow(i) {
        document.getElementById('tabelaBanco').deleteRow(i)
      }

      function pedido() {
        // Percorrer todas as linhas do corpo da tabela
        $('#tabelaPedido tbody tr').each(function () {
          // Recuperar todas as colunas da linha percorida
          var colunas = $(this).children();
          var pedidos = [];
          // Criar objeto para armazenar os dados
          var pedido = {
            'produto': $(colunas[0]).text(), // valor da coluna Produto
            'quantidade': $(colunas[1]).text() // Valor da coluna Quantidade
          };
          // Adicionar o objeto pedido no array
          pedidos.push(pedido);
        });
        // listando os pedidos função teste
        alert(pedidos);
        alert("esta funcionando");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><p>Produto:</p></td>
          <td><p>Quantidade</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="produto" id="cprod"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="quantidade" id="cquant"></td>
          <td><input type='button' id='incluir' class="btn" value='Incluir Produto' onclick='adiciona()'/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id='tabelaPedido' class="table table-hover" border='0' width='100%'>
        <thead>
          <tr style='background-color:#FBF6F7'>
            <td class="produto"><strong>Produto</strong></td>
            <td class="quantidade"><strong>Quantidade</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Excluir</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <!-- chamando a função para pegar os dados e imprimir na telana -->
      <input class="btn" type = "submit" name = "but" value = "Confirmar Pedido" onclick='pedido()'/>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o seu codigo está adicionando novas linhas no corpo da tabela e não no `tbody`, então o seletor `$('#tabelaPedido tbody tr')` não deve está trazendo registros.

em todo caso, estou deixando uma implementação um pouco mais completa para o que deseja fazer:

```js
var handler = {
  tabela: {},
  acoes: {},
  templates: {},
  init: function (tableName) {
    this.templates.novo = document.getElementById("tmplNovo").content;        
    this.templates.editar = document.getElementById("tmplEdit").content;
    this.templates.salvar = document.getElementById("tmplView").content;
    this.templates.cancelar = this.templates.salvar;

    this.tabela.root = document.getElementById(tableName);
    this.tabela.thead = this.tabela.root.querySelector("thead");
    this.tabela.tbody = this.tabela.root.querySelector("tbody");
    this.tabela.tfoot = this.tabela.root.querySelector("tfoot");

    this.acoes.novo = this.tabela.thead.querySelector("[data-action='novo']");
    this.acoes.finalizar = this.tabela.tfoot.querySelector("[data-action='finalizar']");

    this.acoes.novo.addEventListener("click", this);
    this.acoes.finalizar.addEventListener("click", this);

  },
  handleEvent: function (event) {
    var self = this;
    var atual = {};
    var linha = {};
    var action = event.target.dataset.action;

    atual.root = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;  
    if (atual.root.dataset.estado) {
      atual.produto = atual.root.querySelector("[name='produto']");
      atual.quantidade = atual.root.querySelector("[name='quantidade']");
    }

    if (self.templates[action]) {        
      linha.root = document.importNode(self.templates[action], true);    
      linha.actions = linha.root.querySelectorAll("[data-action]");  
      linha.produto = linha.root.querySelector("[name='produto']");
      linha.quantidade = linha.root.querySelector("[name='quantidade']");

      [].forEach.call(linha.actions, function (elem, indice) {
        elem.addEventListener("click", self);
      });
    }

    self[action](event, atual, linha);
  },
  novo: function (event, atual, linha) {
    var self = this;
    self.acoes.novo.disabled = "disabled";
    self.acoes.novo.readOnly = "readOnly";

    self.tabela.tbody.appendChild(linha.root);
    linha.produto.focus();
  },
  salvar: function (event, atual, linha) {
    var self = this;
    if (atual.root.dataset.estado === "novo") {
      self.acoes.novo.disabled = null;
      self.acoes.novo.readOnly = null;
    }

    linha.produto.textContent = atual.produto.value;
    linha.quantidade.textContent = atual.quantidade.value;

    self.tabela.tbody.insertBefore(linha.root, atual.root);
    self.tabela.tbody.removeChild(atual.root);
  },
  apagar: function (event, atual, linha) {
    var self = this;
    if (atual.root.dataset.estado === "novo") {
      self.acoes.novo.disabled = null;
      tselfhselfis.acoes.novo.readOnly = null;
    }
    self.tabela.tbody.removeChild(atual.root);
  },
  editar: function (event, atual, linha) {
    var self = this;

    linha.produto.value = atual.produto.textContent;
    linha.quantidade.value = atual.quantidade.textContent;
    linha.produto.dataset.oldValue = linha.produto.value;
    linha.quantidade.dataset.oldValue = linha.quantidade.value;   

    self.tabela.tbody.insertBefore(linha.root, atual.root);
    self.tabela.tbody.removeChild(atual.root);
    linha.produto.focus();
  },
  cancelar: function (event, atual, linha) {
    var self = this;

    linha.produto.textContent = atual.produto.dataset.oldValue;
    linha.quantidade.textContent = atual.quantidade.dataset.oldValue;

    self.tabela.tbody.insertBefore(linha.root, atual.root);
    self.tabela.tbody.removeChild(atual.root);
  },
  finalizar: function (event) {
    var self = this;

    self.acoes.novo.disabled = null;
    self.acoes.novo.readOnly = null; 

    var pedidos = [];
    var linhas = this.tabela.tbody.querySelectorAll("tr[data-estado]");
    [].forEach.call(linhas, function (linha, indice) {
      var pedido = {};        
      var atual = {};
      atual.produto = linha.querySelector("[name='produto']");
      atual.quantidade = linha.querySelector("[name='quantidade']");

      if (linha.dataset.estado == "view") {
        pedido.produto = atual.produto.textContent;
        pedido.quantidade = atual.quantidade.textContent;
        pedidos.push(pedido);
      }

      if (linha.dataset.estado == "edit") {
        pedido.produto = atual.produto.dataset.oldValue;
        pedido.quantidade = atual.quantidade.dataset.oldValue;
        pedidos.push(pedido);
      }

      self.tabela.tbody.removeChild(linha);
    });

    console.log(pedidos);
  }
}

handler.init("tabela");
```

```css
.action input[type="image"] {
  float: right;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.action-novo:disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
input, span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px;
}

td {
  min-width: 150px;
}

td.action {
  min-width: 48px;
}

#tabela thead tr, #tabela tfoot tr { background: darkgrey; }
#tabela tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: gainsboro}
#tabela tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: whitesmoke}
```

```html
<table id="tabela">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Produto</td>
      <td>Quantidade</td>
      <td class="action">
        <input type="image" data-action="novo"
               src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/66/66820.svg" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="action">
        <input type="image" data-action="finalizar" 
               src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/70/70050.svg" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<template id="tmplNovo">
  <tr data-estado="novo">
    <td><input type="text" name="produto" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantidade" /></td>
    <td class="action">
      <input type="image" data-action="salvar"
             src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/64/64082.svg" />
      <input type="image" data-action="apagar"
             src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/24/24313.svg" />            
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<template id="tmplEdit">
  <tr data-estado="edit">
    <td><input type="text" name="produto" data-old-value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="quantidade" data-old-value="" /></td>
    <td class="action">
      <input type="image" data-action="salvar"
             src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/64/64082.svg" />
      <input type="image" data-action="cancelar"
             src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/61/61918.svg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<template id="tmplView">
  <tr data-estado="view">
    <td><span name="produto"></span></td>
    <td><span name="quantidade"></span></td>
    <td class="action">
      <input type="image" data-action="apagar"
             src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/24/24313.svg" />
      <input type="image" data-action="editar"
             src="http://cdn.flaticon.com/svg/66/66931.svg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Notei que tanto no seu quando no meu exemplo, ambos não usamos o estilo zebrado na tabela, mas pelo fato dele estar usando a biblioteca Bootstrap não se faz necessário o uso desta declaração. O Bootstrap já vem com uma classe especifica para isto certo ?

Comment: @devgaspa, já que mencionou, adicionei um css para tornar a tabela zebrada.

Comment: @devgaspa, e quanto ao Bootstrap ter um estilo para isto, eu realmente não sei, até pq normalmente uso o [datatables.net com o estilo do Bootstrap](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap)

Answer (score 4):

Um dos **erros** evidentes é de fato você não estar adicionando as linhas da tabela no lugar certo, como nesta imagem, ao adicionar dois produtos veja onde foram inseridos no código: [image: Inclusão de produto]

Seu código nem muitas coisas que podem ser melhoradas, tomei a liberdade de desenvolver um script com algumas funcionalidades que lhe ajudaram nos aspectos performance e organização.

Segue exemplo:

```js
var produtos = {
    index : 0,
    tBody: document.getElementById('lstProdBody'),
    pedidos: {}, 
 adicionar: function(e) {
        // Impede de submeter a página.
        e.preventDefault();
     
        var prod = document.getElementById('produto'),
            qtd = document.getElementById('quantidade');
        
        // Cria estrutura de elementos para adicionar a tabela.
        var tr     = document.createElement('tr'),
            tdProd = document.createElement('td'),
            tdQtd  = document.createElement('td'),
            tdBtn  = document.createElement('td'),
            btn    = document.createElement('button');
        
        // Faz o aninhamento dos elementos, atribui os valores adicionados e acrescenta a tabela.
        tdProd.textContent = prod.value;
        tdQtd.textContent = qtd.value;
        
        // Limpa campos.
        prod.value = '';
        qtd.value = '';
        
        btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'produtos.excluir(event, this);');
        btn.textContent = 'Excluir';
        
        tdBtn.appendChild(btn);
        
        tr.appendChild(tdProd);
        tr.appendChild(tdQtd);
        tr.appendChild(tdBtn);
        
        this.tBody.appendChild(tr);
    },
    excluir: function(e, elem) {
        // Impede de submeter a página.
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // Pega o elemento pai do elemento pai do botão e deleta da tabela.
        var a = elem.parentElement.parentElement;
        this.tBody.removeChild(a);
    },
    send: function(e) {
        // Impede de submeter a página.
        e.preventDefault();
        
        // Pega os valores de cada linha da tabela inclui em uma array, apos isto, adiciona no objeto pedidos.
        var pedido = [];
        
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.tBody.children, function(arr, index) {
            pedido.push({'produto': arr.children[0].textContent, 'quantidade': arr.children[1].textContent});
        });
        
        this.pedidos = { "pedido" : pedido };
        
        console.log(this.pedidos);
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cadastro-produtos {
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.lista-produtos {
    width: 100%;
}
.lista-produtos thead tr th {
    background-color: #fbf6f7;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="cadastro-produtos">
        <labe>Produto:</label>
        <input type="text" id="produto">
        <labe>Quantidade:</label>
        <input type="text" id="quantidade">
        <button onclick="produtos.adicionar(event);">Adicionar</button>
    </div>
    <table class="lista-produtos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Excluir</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="lstProdBody">
            <!-- Inclusão dinâmica -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="produtos.send(event);">Confirmar Pedido</button>
    <div id="showJson"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: vendo a sua sugestão, me lembrei que poderia usar um `handleEvent` para ajudar na organização do meu próprio exemplo. quanto ao seu exemplo, ficou muito bom, apenas não entendi a necessidade de atribuir um valor `inline` para o `onclick`, inclusive você o faz no próprio javaScript `btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'produtos.excluir(event, this);');`

Comment: @TobyMosque Isto! olhei agora seu exemplo, ficou legal! não usei a declaração do `onclick` inline por preguiça... rsrs! Obrigado.

Comment: Galera muito obrigado pela atenção mas o evento de adicionar não esta funcionando quais os plugins necessarios para se trabalhar com json e jquery ?