# Preenchimento e envio de formulários com Spring MVC e JSP

Tags: mvc, spring, jsp

Eu estou inciando em ***Java Web***, desenvolvendo um sistema de estoque seguindo a apostila da Caelum de Java para Web.

Todo o `front-end` e a camada de persistência já foram desenvolvidas restando somente a controle integrando as duas, porém eu estou com muitas duvidas quando se trata de obter os dados da pagina para tratá-los, inserir no banco e etc...

Por exemplo na pagina abaixo, eu tenho o Formulário de envios, de acordo com o que ensina a apostila eu tenho que manter os campos nomeados de acordo com os atributos correspondentes da classe Envio, até aí tranquilo, o problema é que dentro do form eu tenho um sub formulario que corresponde a classe `ItemEnvio` e uma tabela, onde eu posso inserir varios itens.

Meu objetivo é preencher um `ArrayList` com os itens adicionados nessa tabela e os dados da parte de cima do form em um objeto Envio, enviar as duas para `controller` e ela adicionar no banco de dados, é a lógica que eu utilizo quando desenvolvo em `Java` usando `Swing` com `JTable` e etc..

Alguém pode dar uma orientação de como proceder?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código da JSP/Html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durante essa semana de pesquisa eu encontrei e já implementei a solução.
1º O preenchimento e a exclusão de linhas é feita por JavaScript seguindo a solução proposta pelo usuário `devgaspa` daqui do fórum nesse tópico [Pegar o valor da tabela javaScript e colocar em um array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98475/pegar-o-valor-da-tabela-javascript-e-colocar-em-um-array)
2º Na função send, eu preenchi um objeto JSON com todas as informação do form, e inclusive, com um array com os dados da tabela. Esse JSON corresponde à classe `Envio` que dentro dela possui um `ArrayList` da Classe `ItemEnvio`. 
Enviei esse JSON para a controller via requisição AJAX seguindo a solução desse tópico https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524524/passing-json-data-to-a-spring-mvc-controller. 
Como toda a manipulação foi feita em JS puro, ao tentar usar o AJAX em JQuery, como mostra a solução, dava erro, então fiz as requisições AJAX em JavaScript puro seguindo esse outro tópico https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468459/sending-a-json-to-server-and-retrieving-a-json-in-return-without-jquery